# jQuery Mobile page width is too wide...

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on creating pages for mobile devices with jQuery Mobile.

Here is the basic page template I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js">
    </script>  
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">    
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">         
      <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        Page Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I try to view this on a mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy, iPhone, etc.) the page width is far too large (forcing scrolling on small resolution devices or very small text on larger resolution devices.)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank-you!

Comment: could you post your CSS?

Comment: @jackJoe - there are no CSS definitions other than the those that come bundled with jQuery mobile

Answer (score 35):

try adding this in the head

```
<head>
.....
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

also one `<div data-role="content"> ... </div>` is enough

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a meta viewport tag to your head to set the page width to device width. It's covered in the blog posts at jquerymobile and updated docs:

[jquerymobile.com/test/](http://jquerymobile.com/test/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the multiple `data-role="content"` are causing a styling issue. The [Anatomy of a Page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html) does not use multiple *content* `data-role` and the [boiler plate](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/page-template.html) template does not either.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with your CSS. Check your `<body>`'s width and height.

For best results, you should use CSS media queries and check for screen resolution, thus having a different style depending on the user's screen.

For further reading:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: I am not using my own CSS rules - only the CSS rules that are built into jQuery Mobile.  jQuery Mobile is supposed to handle detection of screen width and appropriate formatting of content automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with `<div data-role="content">`.

Not sure you can have two of those on a page.

```
<div data-role="content"> 

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            Page Content
        </div>

    </div>
```

The docs don't suggest there could be more than one: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html